# Clicking dropdown arrow of Excel Data Validation entry no longer enters data into cell

Tags: excel, vba, validation

So I have been following this video to prepare a data validation list that is able to auto-complete user entries: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkPoViUhkxU

Essentially at about 10 mins, the instructor demonstrates that when the user types in a letter or part of a word into a data validation cell, when the drop-down of the data validation is clicked this produces a dynamic list of all possible entries.

I am able to produce a dynamic list, but the list is only created when I click off the cell not when the dropdown arrow is depressed as in the video. I was wondering if I am missing a setting here to allow data to be entered into a cell with the dropdown, not just on pressing the enter key?

Any thoughts or guidance would be greatly appreciated,

Matt

Comment: Have you got autocalculate switched on? That was an interesting vid btw, I just tried it out :-)

Comment: I am on a Mac and under "Calculation Options" it reads "Automatic" as the option selected

Comment: I suggest going step by step through the video again. If you have the dynamic list correctly showing on the right, maybe pick up the video from there.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for. http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal11.html This link definitely has a lot more details about how Data Validation is done, compared to that that YouTube video you shared. This is a bit challenging to do in Excel, but keep at it, and you will learn a lot!!

Comment: Hi, I believe I managed to solve this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50079190/5253609

Answer (score 0):

Macros in your file work by change in selection range and they prevent formulas to be evaluated before changing the selection. You should either remove the macro or use another type of event to activate your code.

Comment: Is it possible to add files on here?

Comment: Not sure about the file, but you can add a screenshot or share a link to your file on a public cloud storage.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pddz29w316qu8r5/AutoSearch%20-%20new%20algorithm.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: That is a link to the file on dropbox... strangely with Excel Online the described feature does seem to work. So there must be some setting on the desktop version that is disabling things?

Comment: I believe the problem is because of the subroutines you have. One of the subroutines run anytime the selected range changes. So, it might prevent the formulas to update.

Comment: Could you fix it?

Comment: Well, I  commented out all the subroutines and disabled macros but the formulas still for some reason do not update on the desktop... very strange. Any thoughts?

Comment: Save your file as a normal Excel file (.xlsx) and try again (this will remove any VBA code. So make sure you have a backup). If it doesn't work, it might be a Excel for Mac issue, as it worked fine on my PC.